# How to reload the page after logging out <javascript>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am building a webpage and I'm having issues refreshing the page after I log out. 
What I do when I log out is basically hiding one div and then show the "maindiv" which is basically the main page where you log in. Something like this:

```
function myfunction(){

$("#seconddiv").hide();

$("#maindiv").show();

}
```

This works perfectly fine in order to take me to the main page but when I try to log in again, it won't work. Thanks in advance if you can give me some advice.

Comment: So you're on another 'page', which is whatever is in the thing with id="seconddiv". Then you're calling this function to hide that and show the thing with id="maindiv" and that's working?

Then, you 'try to log in again'. What do you mean by that?

Your question needs filling out a bit more.

Comment: How does the login work? Missing some important details there

Comment: Sorry, I didnt think that was importante since the thing that I actually need is to refresh the page. Michael Rouse got it right, what he suggested worked perfectly. Thank you guys for the help!.

Comment: Probably not needed to reload and just need to reverse above code but if that works great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
window.location.reload()
```